# Происхождение и значение слова "малахольный"

Tags: этимология

Не очень часто встречаемое слово "малахольный". Что оно означает и от какого корня произошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве словрей малАхольный — о человеке со странностями, причудами в поведении либо меланхоличном или плохо соображающем.

Автор "Словаря русского арго" Елистратов предполагает, что это слово восходит к древнееврейскому maloch (ангел, добряк), но это сомнительно. Скорее, каким-то образом от "меланхоличный" оно и образовалось.

Answer (score 4):

Викисловарь даёт ссылку на [статью Л.В. Куркиной](http://elar.urfu.ru/bitstream/10995/26887/1/ei_1978_05.pdf) 1978 г. из первого выпуска "Этимологических исследований". Там обнаруживается связь слова *малохольный* с группой славянских слов с корнем **млах** и значениями типа *слабый, вялый*. Сюда же относится церковно-славянское "млохальство" с тем же значением. Далее Куркина даёт профессиональное (а не народно-поэтическое) объяснение образования слова *малохольных* от корня **млах**.

В добротном 7-томном этимологическом словаре украинского языка есть словарная статья  **малахольный**, в которой сказано, что происхождение слова не совсем понятно, и приводится только версия Л.В. Куркиной со ссылкой на её работу.

Comment: Прочитал. Я знал эту версию, это конечно, много лучше чем "еврейский след" г-н Елистратова. Но, опять же, современное значение несколько отличается от просто "слабый". Вот если бы перекинуть этимологический мостик наподобие перехода от просто "слабый" к "слабый умом", а от него уже к чудаковатому персонажу, каковых обычно малахольными и величают... Но пока что такая цепочка  представляется не слишком аргументированной. У Куркиной объяснений нет, да и вообще она, имхо, злоупотребляет аргументацией типа "можно предположить", "по нашим сведениям" и проч.

Comment: @behemothus Никак не могу отстаивать её точку зрения, но решил принести её сюда, чтобы хоть как-то разбавить уже даже не "народную", а просто "персональную" этимологию :)

Comment: Да, я понял. И правильно сделали, что разбавили.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть еще одно предположение. Раньше считалось, что характер человека определяется четырьмя жидкостями организма: желчью (холе), слизья (флегма), кровью (сангва) и черной желчью (меланхоле). Отсюда название темпераментов. Так вот, желчь определяла взрывной, холерический темперамент. А "малахольный" - это некто незаметный, тихий, не от мира сего.
Но это только мое предположение.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что слово имеет две составляющих: "мало" и "холить" - ухаживать, уделять усиленное внимание. Поэтому вкупе получаем "малохольный" (малахольный) - т.е. тот, на кого не следует обращать внимание, поскольку человек этот незначительный.

Answer (score 0):

Версию о происхождении этого слова от древрееврейского "ангел" (מַלְאָך, в ашкеназском произношении "малох") поддерживает и М. М. Фридман в статье 1931 года "[Еврейские элементы "блатной музыки"](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/fridman-31.htm)".

Answer (score -1):

Елистратов прав. Слово прилагательное "малахольный" пришло из церковного лексикона. Это не сложносочинённое слово "мало+холёный". Производное его от существительного имени собственного "Малах". Огласовки диалектически и языково, понятно, могут быть разными. Тем не менее последняя русская версия грамматически через "а". Малах - это древнееврейское божество добра и милосердия. От него произошло имя Малахия. Библейский ветхозаветный пророк Малахия жил около 400 лет до н.э. День почитания у православных 16 января по новому стилю. Другой Святой Малахия жил в 11 веке в Испании в период раскола христианства, поэтому в каноны православия не вошёл. Древнееврейский символ милосердия и добра Малах перешёл в иудейскую культуру в образе ангела смерти, посредника между богом и человеком. Религиознокультурные противоречия, связанные с именем Малах, приобрели негативный оттенок к этому имени в православии, несмотря на почитание Святого Малахии. В лингвистике светского русского языка церковное имя Малахия озвучивается именами Малахий, Малахей, Малафей. Каноническая приверженность к пророку Малахии и религиозная неприязнь к иноверному Малаху и католическому Малахии произвели двусмысленное противоречивое прилагательное слово "малахольный", то есть : святой, но не каждый наш;  ангел - да не тот; символ добра и милосердия - да не православный, а иноверный. Светское слово "малахольный" имеет сейчас немного насмешливый оттенок, обозначая вовсе не иноверца, а любого не по делу доброго, милосердного, нерешительного, неуверенного, но вполне порядочного человека. Церковные же служители характеризуют этим словом также агностиков и атеистов.
Слово "малахольный" оценивает не характер человека, а его поведение. То есть, повёл ты себя не по правилам православной морали, значит смалахольничал.
Это слово ещё активно употреблялось в русской речи вплоть до середины 20-го века, что подтверждает большое наличие его в произведениях классиков русской и украинской литературы. Будучи архаичным и, приобретая обзывательские черты, "малахольный" постепенно стало выходить из употребления в атеистический период культуры, став устаревшим словом. И уже в послесоветское время оно чаще присутствует в речи служителей культа во время мирских бесед.

Comment: Всё бы ничего, но значение слова "малахольный" никак в эту теорию не вписывается. и обилие текста никак эту ситуацию не исправляет.